# Replacing elements of one string with corresponding elements of another in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a program that I am writing some symbols have to be replaced by another throughout the entire program. I've tried doing it this way, but it didn't work.

```
for letter in word:
   letter = letter.replace("a","b").replace("c","d").replace("e","f")
```

Since I'm a beginner, I am asking for a comprehensive solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should apply this chain of replacements to the whole string, not individual characters:

```
word.replace("Ä","AE").replace("Ü","UE").replace("Ö","OE").replace("ß","SS")
```

You don't need to split it into words for this, either.

Answer (score 0):

There is another string method that you could consider when making many replacements at once.

`str.replace` is better when making one substitution various times in a string.

`str.translate` uses a mapping of such changes to make them all in one substitution.

```
teststring = "BAßÜKÖNÄ" # a made-up word

mapping = str.maketrans({"Ä":"AE", "Ü": "UE", "Ö":"OE", "ß":"SS"})
print(teststring.translate(mapping)) # BASSUEKOENAE
```

I think that using `translate` it is easier to check, test and maintain the changes, than using multiple `replace`. `str.maketrans` also allows to use of two strings of equal size that correspond character by character, And even a third argument that maps to the characters you wish to eliminate from the string.